# How to use display tkinter GUIs in Flask or is there a way turning it into html

Tags: html, flask, tkinter

I made this Tkinter GUI and i recently started learning flask.i wanted to add tkinter to my flask website do i have to somehow convert it into HTML?

Comment: You cannot use a desktop GUI application inside Flask.  You need to convert it using HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is designed for desktop UI, and it would require a lot of work to rewrite the drawing part of tkinter to render HTML, so I can say that it's just impossible.

I'd suggest you looking into the templates rendering of Flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

That said, you'd need to do describe your UI in the HTML file and make your Flask HTTP endpoint render this file.